# SED command to replace "[Word1 Word2]" to nothing

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, replace

I am looking for the sed command to replace text like this "[word1 word2]" to nothing.

I tried

```
sed -i -e 's/[Word1 Word2]//g'
```

It didn't work and replaced entire my text in disorder way.

I would like to request you to help me to replace special characters like these.

Thanking you,
Punith.

Comment: `sed  -e 's/\[Word1 Word2\]//g'`

Comment: escape the square brackets \[.....\]

Answer (score 7):

The square brackets `[` and `]` are special characters in `sed`. You must escape them with a backslash, like so:

`sed -i -e 's/\[Word1 Word2\]//g'`